# Video Stabilization Using Point Feature Matching WITHOUT LOSING RGB COLORS on frames on MATLAB

Tags: matlab, video-processing

I'd like to stabilize a 13 min video captured by a quadcopter over a traffic crossroads without losing its 3 color channels (RGB). Matlab's own function leads to a gray scale video which is an unwanted case for the main and future objective, vehicle tracking. New thoughts are appreciated.

Below you can find my own code (works and converts the video to gray scale) edited over the Matlab's own script written on the following page:
[Matlab's related Webpage : Video Stabilization Using Point Feature Matching](https://de.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/video-stabilization-using-point-feature-matching.html)

```
clc; clear all; close all;

filename = 'Quad_video_erst';
hVideoSrc = vision.VideoFileReader('Quad_video_erst.mp4', 'ImageColorSpace', 'Intensity');

% Create and open video file
myVideo = VideoWriter('vivi.avi');        
open(myVideo);
hVPlayer = vision.VideoPlayer;   

%% Step 1: Read Frames from a Movie File

for i=1:10 % testing for a short run 

    imgA = step(hVideoSrc); % Read first frame into imgA
    imgB = step(hVideoSrc); % Read second frame into imgB


%% Step 2: SURF DETECTION

pointsA=surf_function_CAN(imgA);
pointsB=surf_function_CAN(imgB);



%% Step 3. Select Correspondences Between Points
% Extract FREAK descriptors for the corners
[featuresA, pointsA] = extractFeatures(imgA, pointsA);
[featuresB, pointsB] = extractFeatures(imgB, pointsB);

indexPairs = matchFeatures(featuresA, featuresB);
pointsA = pointsA(indexPairs(:, 1), :);
pointsB = pointsB(indexPairs(:, 2), :);


%% Step 4: Estimating Transform from Noisy Correspondences
[tform, pointsBm, pointsAm] = estimateGeometricTransform(...
    pointsB, pointsA, 'affine');
imgBp = imwarp(imgB, tform, 'OutputView', imref2d(size(imgB)));
pointsBmp = transformPointsForward(tform, pointsBm.Location);


%% Step 5: Step 5. Transform Approximation and Smoothing

% Extract scale and rotation part sub-matrix.
H = tform.T;
R = H(1:2,1:2);
% Compute theta from mean of two possible arctangents
theta = mean([atan2(R(2),R(1)) atan2(-R(3),R(4))]);
% Compute scale from mean of two stable mean calculations
scale = mean(R([1 4])/cos(theta));
% Translation remains the same:
translation = H(3, 1:2);
% Reconstitute new s-R-t transform:
HsRt = [[scale*[cos(theta) -sin(theta); sin(theta) cos(theta)];...
  translation], [0 0 1]'];
tformsRT = affine2d(HsRt);

imgBold = imwarp(imgB, tform, 'OutputView', imref2d(size(imgB)));
imgBsRt = imwarp(imgB, tformsRT, 'OutputView', imref2d(size(imgB)));


%% Write the Video
writeVideo(myVideo,imfuse(imgBold,imgBsRt,'ColorChannels','red-cyan'));


end
```

And the function:

```
function [ surf_points ] = surf_function_CAN(img)


surfpoints_raw= detectSURFFeatures(img);
[featuresOriginal,  validPtsOriginal]  = extractFeatures(img,  surfpoints_raw);
strongestPoints = validPtsOriginal.selectStrongest(1600);

array=strongestPoints.Location;

% New - Get X and Y coordinates

X = array(:,1);
Y = array(:,2);

% New - Determine a mask to grab the points we want

ind = (((X>156-9-70 & X<156+9+70) & (Y>406-9-70 & Y<406+9+70)) | ...
((X>684-11-70 & X<684+11+70) & (Y>274-11-70 & Y<274+11+70)) | ...
((X>1066-15-70 & X<1066+15+70) & (Y>67-15-70 & Y<67+15+70)) | ...
((X>1559-15-70 & X<1559+15+70) & (Y>867-15-70 & Y<867+15+70)) | ...
((X>1082-18-70 & X<1082+18+70) & (Y>740-18-100 & Y<740+18+100)))  ;

% New - Create new SURFPoints structure that contains all information
% from the points we need

array_filtered =strongestPoints(ind);
surf_points= array_filtered;

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, if you look through their example you should use the part where they perform the loop, not the part where they show how to implement it between 2 frames as they are not exactly compatible. Other than that the only thing you need to do is perform the analysis on the a grayscale image, but implement the transformation on the color image:

```
%% Load Video and Open Save File
filename = 'shaky_car.avi';
hVideoSrc = vision.VideoFileReader(filename);

myVideo = VideoWriter('vivi.avi');
open(myVideo);

% Get next Image
colorImg = step(hVideoSrc);
% Try to Convert to Grayscale
try
    imgB = rgb2gray(colorImg);
    RGB = true;
catch % Image is not RGB
    imgB = colorImg;
    RGB = false;
end

Hcumulative = eye(3);
ptThresh = 0.1;
% Loop Through Video
while ~isDone(hVideoSrc)
    imgA = imgB;
    % Get Next Image
    colorImg = step(hVideoSrc);
    % Convert to Grayscale
    if RGB
        imgB = rgb2gray(colorImg);
    else
        imgB = colorImg;
    end

    %% Calculate Transformation
    % Generate Prospective Points
    pointsA = detectFASTFeatures(imgA, 'MinContrast', ptThresh);
    pointsB = detectFASTFeatures(imgB, 'MinContrast', ptThresh);

    % Extract Features for the Corners
    [featuresA, pointsA] = extractFeatures(imgA, pointsA);
    [featuresB, pointsB] = extractFeatures(imgB, pointsB);

    indexPairs = matchFeatures(featuresA, featuresB);
    pointsA = pointsA(indexPairs(:, 1), :);
    pointsB = pointsB(indexPairs(:, 2), :);

    [tform] = estimateGeometricTransform(pointsB, pointsA, 'affine');

    % Extract Rotation & Translations
    H = tform.T;
    R = H(1:2,1:2);

    theta = mean([atan2(R(2),R(1)) atan2(-R(3),R(4))]);

    scale = mean(R([1 4])/cos(theta));

    translation = H(3, 1:2);

    % Reconstitute Trnasform
    HsRt = [[scale*[cos(theta) -sin(theta); sin(theta) cos(theta)]; ...
        translation], [0 0 1]'];
    Hcumulative = HsRt*Hcumulative;

    % Perform Transformation on Color Image
    img = imwarp(colorImg, affine2d(Hcumulative),'OutputView',imref2d(size(imgB)));

    % Save Transformed Color Image to Video File
    writeVideo(myVideo,img)
end
close(myVideo)
```

Comment: Thanks for the insights, but unfortunately I can't really use a compact Matlab function such as: `H = cvexEstStabilizationTform(imgA,imgB); HsRt = cvexTformToSRT(H); Hcumulative = HsRt * Hcumulative; ` the reason is I have to make a filtration of the specific points as stable points so that the algorithm can stabilise the video with regards to these references.That's why I chose the longer code in the example on the website.  Originally my code is a bit different than the one I wrote above. Now I updated my question with my original code and the function working with it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have updated my answer to not include the compact Matlab functions.